# Save video from WPF animation / storyboard

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a really complex `Storyboard` which works perfectly when run on a "live" window but I have trouble manually animating this storyboard to get a frame-by-frame animation which I can save to individual PNG files. All of the generated images are 1st animation frame.

I have see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/764770/how-to-render-wpf-animation-as-a-video-frame-by-frame), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1462385/is-is-possible-to-record-my-wpf-control-to-a-movie), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1454158/creating-video-from-wpf-silverlight-animation) and ultimately [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/saveenr/archive/2008/09/22/wpf-xaml-saving-an-animation-as-an-avi-video-file.aspx). There is also [this MSDN sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.clockcontroller.aspx) but all of them talk about animating a single `DependencyProperty`. What I need is the ability to step through frame by frame having a complex `Storyboard`, not just one DP.

I have searched everywhere without any luck. Also my experiments have all failed. Any help is appreciated. Here is a bit of non-functional code.

```
            storyboard.Begin(grid, true);
            //storyboard.Pause();
            //var clock = storyboard.CreateClock();
            //clock.Controller.Pause();
            var secs = Enumerable.Range(0, totalFrames).Select(t => (((double)t) / FPS));

            grid.Measure(new Size(480, 340));
            grid.Arrange(new Rect(grid.DesiredSize));

            foreach (var sec in secs)
            {
                //clock.Controller.SeekAlignedToLastTick(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(sec), TimeSeekOrigin.BeginTime);
                storyboard.SeekAlignedToLastTick(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(sec), TimeSeekOrigin.BeginTime);
                grid.InvalidateVisual();
                grid.UpdateLayout();

                var filename = Path.Combine(tempFolder, string.Format("image{0}.png", sec));
                var rtb = new RenderTargetBitmap((int) grid.ActualWidth, (int) grid.ActualHeight, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
                rtb.Render(grid);

                var png = new PngBitmapEncoder();
                png.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(rtb));

                using (var stream = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
                {
                    png.Save(stream);
                }
            }
```

Comment: Hey hi...I am stuck with the similar problem. I animated a cube to translate along Z axis. Now I want to make video of the animation but its just showing the single image. Interestingly the same code can make the video of the simple animation like ellipse moving around on the canvas. I know it's been more than 2 years since you posted this, but it would be really helpful if you could share some sample code or point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

@wpfwannabe: thanks a lot for the insight.

I used your code and it worked out, although with a minor modification as shown below:

```
rootStoryBoard.SeekAlignedToLastTick(Program.AnimPlots.canvs, TargetTmspn, System.Windows.Media.Animation.TimeSeekOrigin.BeginTime);
```

In the above line of code: `Program.AnimPlots.canvs` is the area of snapshot, in your case it is `grid` and `TargetTmspn` is the object of type `TimeSpan`.

Hope this helps someone :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's another approach that you may find useful. If you've exhausted all options for animating your XAML Storyboard frame-by-frame then another option you could explore would be to create your Storyboard in code instead, here's an example: [Animation in codebehind for loop, using RenderTransform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10115657/animation-in-codebehind-for-loop-using-rendertransform/10116770#10116770)

The benefit of that is then you'd have total programmatic control over your Storyboard to step through the individual key frames one-by-one, where you could then save an image after each frame.

I did something conceptually similar in jQuery a while back. Basically I wrote a line drawing signature app that saved coordinate data points. I could then reload the data points back into the algorithm and reproduce the animation. http://kodekreachor.com/prototypes/

I know it's a very different technology but it's the idea of being able to completely control the sequential animation from code that should be the take-away and hopefully serve as some inspiration for you.